# Storing a form submitted Image in a django ImageField within specific folder

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django model form. One of the fields in the form is a ImageField with a set path to a specific folder to store the images. I want to grab the image that is submitted with the form and name of the image. I want the image itself store in the folder and the name to store in the database to be able to grab it whenever I need it. I looked around and there were not usable answers to fixing this problem for me. Here is my code:

Models.py:

```
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/profile_pics/', height_field=500, width_field=500, max_length=100)
    bio = models.TextField()
```

views.py:

```
        if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            first_name = cd['first_name']
            last_name = cd['last_name']
            profile_pic = cd['profile_pic']
            bio = cd['bio']
            new_profile = Profile.objects.create(
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                bio = bio,
                profile_pic = profile_pic,
                dob = dob,
            )
```

this is what is sent in the request:

[image]

Here is the directly with the path I want to store the images in.

[image]

---

UPDATE:

here is the models.py model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profile_pics/', max_length=100)
    bio = models.TextField()
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=44)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField()
    group = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is the forms.py file:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=22,
        label="First Name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=22,
        label="Last Name")
    dob = forms.DateField(
        label='Date of Birth',
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'})
    )
    gender_choices = (('M', 'Male'),
                      ('F', 'Female'),
                      ('O', 'Other'))
    gender = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices = gender_choices,
        label='Gender')
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_pic', 'bio', 'dob', 'company',
                  'occupation', 'gender', 'phone', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code']
```

Here is the template:

Profile:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="complete" value="complete">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you check what `cd['profile_pic']` has as the value?

Comment: that is the first image `cd['profile_pic']` is  `profile_pic:MySplit_Logo_blue.png` @EminBuğraSaral

Comment: One problem is that you are not passing the file to the form like this: `ProfileForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES)` So I am not sure if it's returning just a string or a file.

Comment: Also you need to make sure that you added the `encytype="multipart/form-data"` on your html form definition, i always forgot that.

Comment: do i add the `encytype="multipart/form-data"` in the forms.py file with the profile form in the imagefield description.... @LuanFonseca

Comment: @OmarJandali No, you need to add it to your `<form>` definition, inside some html file. See the docs for this parameter: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: I added it to my form, but it is still saying that the field is required... @LuanFonseca could it be somthing I am missing in the directlyo or settings, becuase the image name is being passed in the request, but it is not recognized when i try to start processing

Comment: @OmarJandali, can be that. I think that, by default django creates a folder called `media` to store that uploads. Look over the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload_to parameter refers to the relative path inside the "media" folder, it is not relative to the root path. To get this to work, first you have to specify the media root in your settings.py and then the path below will tell django to put all the uploaded images to /media/images/profile_pics/.

[upload_to Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)

```
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profile_pics/', height_field=500, width_field=500, max_length=100)
```

In order for the form to save the images you have to provide your form with the files as well.

```
# this way the form have access to the file uploaded in the buffer
form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: i forgot to add the error that I am getting I am going to update my post iwth the error I am getting at the top

Comment: It is saying that `the image field is required`, does that mean that it is not recognizing the image or what is going on...

Comment: I am getting the following error now: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>profile_pic<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>` and I added the `request.FILES` I also changed the `upload_to='images/profile_pics/`... do i need to do anything in the settings...

Comment: can you post your form and the template where you render the form?

Comment: does django automatically save thelife in the folder designated as upload_to and then save the link in the database...

Comment: only if you save using the form.save() method, otherwise you have to handle the save your self.